# install4j: how to create uninstall log files like the install log file

Tags: uninstallation, install4j

I purchased the install4j to make my Java installer, which is in good condition, after the installation is complete, I can find the xx/installDir/. Install4j/installation.log file, this is what I want, but I also want to uninstall.log file, I temporarily didn't find such a configuration, I need the uninstall.log file, which is generated in the installation directory after uninstalled.  So that users can view the uninstall information after uninstall. how can i do , Thanks!

Comment: you should probably check with vendor.

Comment: Thanks for your reminder !

Comment: If I get the answer I'll write it over here

Comment: We monitor the install4j tag and answer all appropriate questions

Answer (score 3):

There is no permanent place for the uninstallation log because the installation directory will be deleted.

You can pass

```
-Dinstall4j.keepLog=true
```

to the uninstaller, so the temporary log file in the `%TEMP%` directory will not be deleted. To save it somewhere else, pass

```
-Dinstall4j.alternativeLogfile=[path to writable log file]
```

to the uninstaller.